# Monotouch: Remove all subviews from a view

Tags: xamarin.ios, subview

I am trying to remove all the subviews from a UIView. I tried the following to no effect:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Subviews.Length; i++)
        {
            this.Subviews[i].RemoveFromSuperview ();

        }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just tested this and it worked for me. (Although your code also looks good to me...)

```
foreach (UIView view in tableView.Subviews) {
  view.RemoveFromSuperview();
}
```

If it doesn't work for you, there might be something that prevents the subviews from being removed.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your sample is how you built the loop.

When you remove the view at 0, the Subviews array is one element shorter, and element 1 becomes element 0 on the next iteration.   Your i variable on the other hand keeps growing, so you end up skipping view 1.

Comment: Something 0-based could work around that, right? Like `while (this.Subviews.Length > 0) { this.Subviews[0].RemoveFromSuperview(); }`

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing a refresh of the view afterward, or invoking the Remove call specifically on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need to use an for loop, this will do

```
    for (int i = this.Subviews.Length - 1 ; i > 0  i--)
    {
        this.Subviews[i].RemoveFromSuperview ();
    }
```